# How do I add -fno-integrated-as to make?

Tags: clang

I'm not really sure if this is a CPPFLAG, a CXXFLAG, a LDFLAG, or just a CFLAG. I'm trying to figure that out, but I'm not really sure which one it is. If someone can tell me what flag it is, that would be awesome!

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thank you in advanced!

Red Prez

Comment: Are the files which contain inline assembly C files or C++ files? If the former, it's a CFLAG. If it's the latter, it's a CXXFLAG.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes a lot of sense! Thank you for the information and help! I'm trying to build an Android kernel and macOS was giving me issues about the assembler being deprecated and to migrate to the integrated Clang assembler. So, this information is super helpful to me! Thank you!